# how to scrape website with dynamic class names?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping restaurants from yelp.com but the website is constantly changing class names. I cannot use xpath since I am using a for loop to loop and extract record of multiple blocks having same class name (this class name is not changing). How can I scrape this website?  Below is the code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(15)

main = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/yelp-react-root/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/main/div/ul")

main_box = main.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.container__09f24__mpR8_.hoverable__09f24__wQ_on.css-1qn0b6x")

for x in main_box:

    try:
        link = x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.businessName__09f24__EYSZE.css-1jq1ouh").get_attribute("href")
        rest_link.append(link)
    except:
        rest_link.append("NA")

    try:
        title = x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.css-19v1rkv").text
        rest_name.append(title)
    except:
        rest_name.append("NA")

print(rest_link)
print(rest_name)
```

I tried class names, tag names, etc

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more details about the HTML. Can you rely on structural information to find which elements to traverse?

Comment: i rely on css class which is changing every 5 monutes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use static selectors like HTML tags, ids over dynamic one. Also try to avoid several lists to store information, use dicts instead, these could simply converted into dataframes or other structures:

```
...
driver.maximize_window()

main_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "main li:has(h3)")
        )
)

data = []

for x in main_box:
    data.append(
        {
            'link': x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a").get_attribute("href") if x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a") else None,
            'title': x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h3").text if x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h3") else None
        }
    )

print(data)
```

Comment: Should I use Tag name instead of CSS selector in above code?

Comment: If you like you could uses also `TAG_NAME`, result should be the same for single tags, but if you need combination or chaining `CSS_SELECTOR` is a much simpler notation or use `XPATH` butr that was not the point. You should not use dynamic class names.